# Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[verify-system-status]'

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I see below error while I am trying to install chef server in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I followed below steps to install chef server from one of Sachin blog. 
https://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/tag/chef-server/

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-server/11.1.7/ubuntu/12.04/chef-server_11.1.7-1_amd64.deb

dpkg -i chef-server-core_*.deb

rm chef-server-core_*.deb

chef-server-ctl reconfigure

chef-server-ctl restart

My /etc/hosts files include my hostname.

127.0.0.1       localhost howareu
127.0.1.1       howareu
172.25.150.19 howareu localhost

Error Logs-

```
    root@Jenkins:~# chef-server-ctl reconfigure
    the ffi-yajl and yajl-ruby gems have incompatible C libyajl libs and should not be loaded in the same Ruby VM
    falling back to ffi which might work (or might not, no promises)
    [2017-10-16T17:17:39+05:30] WARN:
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
    encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
    attacks.
To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:
# Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
      ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer
# OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
      verify_api_cert true
To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
    `knife ssl check` command like so:
knife ssl check -c /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/solo.rb
Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.2
    Compiling Cookbooks...
    Recipe: chef-server::default
      * directory[/etc/chef-server] action create (up to date)
    [2017-10-16T17:17:41+05:30] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[/opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start postgresql] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
    [2017-10-16T17:17:41+05:30] WARN: Previous execute[/opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start postgresql]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/postgresql.rb:128:in `from_file'
    [2017-10-16T17:17:41+05:30] WARN: Current  execute[/opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start postgresql]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/postgresql.rb:175:in `from_file'
    [2017-10-16T17:17:42+05:30] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
    [2017-10-16T17:17:42+05:30] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/chef-server-webui.rb:31:in `block in from_file'
    [2017-10-16T17:17:42+05:30] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/chef-server/chef-server-webui/etc]: /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/definitions/unicorn_config.rb:21:in `block in from_file'
    Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
    .......+++
    .............................................................+++
    e is 65537 (0x10001)
    Converging 216 resources
      * directory[/etc/chef-server] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    Recipe: chef-server::users
      * user[chef_server] action create (up to date)
      * group[chef_server] action create (up to date)
    Recipe: chef-server::default
      * directory[/etc/chef] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/var/opt/chef-server] action create (up to date)
    Recipe: runit::upstart
      * execute[initctl stop opscode-runsvdir] action run (skipped due to only_if)
      * file[/etc/init/opscode-runsvdir.conf] action delete (up to date)
      * cookbook_file[/etc/init/chef-server-runsvdir.conf] action create (up to date)
      * execute[initctl status chef-server-runsvdir] action run
        - execute initctl status chef-server-runsvdir
Recipe: chef-server::bootstrap
      * execute[verify-system-status] action run
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[verify-system-status]'Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '22'
    ---- Begin output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
    STDOUT:
    STDERR:
    ---- End output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
    Ran curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status returned 22


    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/bootstrap.rb

     24: execute "verify-system-status" do
     25:   command "curl -sf #{erchef_status_url}"
     26:   retries 20
     27:   not_if { File.exists?(bootstrap_status_file) }
     28: end
     29:
Compiled Resource:
    # Declared in /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/bootstrap.rb:24:in `from_file'
    execute("verify-system-status") do
      action "run"
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      guard_interpreter :default
      command "curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      cookbook_name :"chef-server"
      recipe_name "bootstrap"
      not_if { #code block }
    end Running handlers:
    [2017-10-16T17:18:30+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    Running handlers complete

    [2017-10-16T17:18:30+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    [2017-10-16T17:18:30+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    Chef Client failed. 12 resources updated in 51.2651677 seconds
    [2017-10-16T17:18:30+05:30] ERROR: execute[verify-system-status] (chef-server::bootstrap line 24) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '22'
    ---- Begin output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
    STDOUT:
    STDERR:
    ---- End output of curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status ----
    Ran curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status returned 22
    [2017-10-16T17:18:30+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: what happens if you manually try to curl http://127.0.0.1:8000? error 22 is typically  an invalid argument.

Comment: @JackChance this results in blank.

root@Jenkins:/etc/chef-server# curl -sf http://127.0.0.1:8000/_status

Comment: Why do you have localhost in /etc/hosts twice? That seems like a mistake.

Comment: @coderanger Removed it.. Still same error